# Win8: WriteableBitmap.Render support?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

In Windows 8 App, I want to take a "screenshot" of a specific hierarchy of visual tree, it looks like `WriteableBitmap.Render` is not supported even in Windows 8 RTM. Are there any other ways to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to simply pickle the visual tree into a WriteableBitmap.  You can get the [raw pixel stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer.aspx) out and manipulate it.  Check out [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/)  -- I don't think it replaces Render functionality, but it is a great example of how to work with a WriteableBitmaps in WinRT.

Comment: Hi JP Alioto, thanks for your answer. The problem is, how to get the raw pixel stream out for a visual tree, any sample code?

Answer (score 1):

I have just worked on it for a very short time, but I am working on implementing some basic composition code to render a visual tree to a bitmap. Got it working for some basic TextBlocks for now, but I might add other pieces soon too. You can use the code to add the elements you need in your scenario.

http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/585d3ae5a3e3#WinRTXamlToolkit.Composition%2fWriteableBitmapRenderExtensions.cs